# 280LM Led Headlamp needs FCC certificate?

Tags: led, lithium-ion, lithium, fcc

Do I need FCC certification for my 280LM Led Headlamp with 1800MAH Lithium battery which is rechargeable only via USB?

More details:
Watts out: 3W
Lithium-ion Cells: 103450
Energy Content:1800Mah
Battery Voltage:3.7V
Battery Weight:32g

It already has CE and ROHS certifications, would that make any help for getting FCC?

Thank you in advance

Comment: RoHS is unrelated. You might want to ask about the CE 'certification' and who tested it- if self-certified, ask to see the test reports. You can buy big rolls of CE stickers at Chinese markets. Just sayin'..

Answer (score 1):

FCC certifications (USA) are generally only needed on commercial products that may radiate levels of AC energy over about 10khz.  If your device operates only in a DC mode then there is no FCC requirement.

The USB recharging, as with many other products, only uses the DC power from the connection.

CE covers all sorts of different certification topics for EU countries.  ROHS deals only with Hazard Substances.

On top of that, only the manufacturer needs to acquire the FCC certifications, not the user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Nedd. In this case I am the retailer and Im thinking about importing this product from China to US. Should i be worried about FCC in this case?

Comment: I see a lot of led headlamps that uses 3AAA battery's and has FCC certificate label on their packaging. Regarding your answer they shouldn't need it in the first place for being able to sell in the US as it is also a DC power right? Why do they have it then?

Comment: Does the headlight have a dimmer function? If so, it may use PWM with variable duty cycle to do it. In that case, FCC cert may be necessary.

Comment: It doesnt have a dimmer function. All though i found this regarding the FCC requirements:  Digital devices that include, or make provision for the use of, battery eliminators, AC adaptors or battery chargers which permit operation while charging or that connect to the AC power lines indirectly, obtaining their power through another device which is connected to the AC power lines, do not fall under this exemption. My headlight plugs in to the usb port which plugs in to adapter which is connected to AC power so that means i still need FCC if i understand this correctly or not?

Comment: The external charger/battery eliminator should have its own safety/FCC markings if needed.  Still the manufacturer should be responsible to either obtain the certification (and copy the seller) or explain (or certify) that such certification is not required.  Foreign imports often include CE markings which might also satisfy FCC requirements, but again the manufacturer should be able to provide proof of the actual type of CE certification, and if additional FCC marking is needed.  (Overall - does the manufacturer consider the product a "Digital" device???)